# Making responsive grid elements fit by height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I'm trying to get my head around working with responsive webdesign (by column stacking) and I'm currently using this grid for my layouts: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ which I think works quite neat.

Only thing I'm running my head the wall with is to make it "smart enough" to also try and fit my columns by their height. What I have so far is this: http://gridtest.uconsult.dk/ and what I'm looking for is this: http://gridtest.uconsult.dk/gridheight.png so that the grid is trying to fit the rows by their height aswell as the column count.

Is this possible in some way? :-) Should I by using some other grid for this or do I have to make up some hacky javascript to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel!  David DeSandro already put out a couple jquery plugins that will do this for you.  [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) was the first one and works very well, and [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) is the newer version that expanded on the original thinking along with additional features like sorting.  Both will do a good job of creating the dynamic grid system you're hoping for.

Comment: Definitely do not reinwheel the vent. Especially on something like this. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) I went with the masonry jQuery plugin, works wonders!